# Event Date timezone issue in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, datetime, timezone, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I am facing one issue related to event dates in fullcalendar. I am passing below JSON for creating recurring event

```
{"status":true,"data":[{"id":7,"title":"Start%20creating%20your%20amazing%20application%21","description":"","eStart":"2020-11-03 04:00","rrule":{"freq":"weekly","interval":1,"byweekday":[1,2],"dtstart":"2020-11-02","until":"2020-11-16"},"eEnd":"2020-11-04 05:00","start":"2020-11-02T17:00:00.000Z","end":"2020-11-03T18:00:00.000Z","backgroundColor":"#dd0d0d","assigned_users":[2,89],"isMilestone":false,"allDay":false,"timezone":"+05:30","timezoneId":55,"creator":89,"companyId":2,"created_at":"2020-11-19T06:33:35.000Z","updated_at":"2020-11-19T09:37:28.000Z","userTimezone":"+05:30","duration":{"days":1}}]}
```

eStart("2020-11-03 04:00") and eEnd ("2020-11-04 05:00") dates are used to display event, but on fullcalendar it changes the date and show date eStart("2020-11-02 22:30") and eEnd ("2020-11-02 23:30"). eStart and eEnd date are already converted to new timezone.

I need to show dates as it is coming from server.

[image]

Comment: Have you read https://fullcalendar.io/docs/timeZone yet? Please also show your current calendar code.

Comment: @ADyson Yes. I have read the documentation. There are three parameters for timezone: local, UTC and you can specify timezone string. But I don't want to use that. I am converting dates and timezone on server side. I want to show date as it is on fullcalendar.

Comment: @ADyson Is there any way to stop date modification on fullcalendar side?

Comment: Well as the documentation says, if you set timezone "local", then `If your dates were supplied as ISO8601 strings without UTC offsets, they will be parsed (and thus displayed) as if they were local`. Note the **without UTC offsets** there. In  other words, remove the timezone info from the dates in your JSON and it should be fine.

Comment: P.S. I'm not sure what "converting dates and timezone on server side" means precisely, but it _sounds_ like you are pre-converting the dates to the user's local timezone before you put them into JSON? If so, then why are you putting `Z` on the end of those dates - because that indicates that the date is in UTC, and therefore if the date is actually in a local timezone, the `Z` is misleading and is confusing fullCalendar.

Comment: P.P.S. I'd say actually in many ways that a simpler and neater option is to leave the dates in UTC on your server, send them as UTC in the JSON (with the `Z` marker to indicate that) and let the browser/fullCalendar handle translating them to the local timezone automatically. Obviously you can do it your way if you prefer, but in that case you need to do it correctly as per the documentation.

Comment: Also you say `eStart("2020-11-03 04:00") and eEnd ("2020-11-04 05:00") dates are used to display event`, but actually fullCalendar always uses `start` and `end` - unless you have somehow customised it? I guess not, because when you use `2020-11-02T17:00:00.000Z` , 17:00 becomes 22:30 when converted to your Chennai timezone (a difference of 5hrs 30min). i don't see how eStart or eEnd are being used at all - although of course since you didn't share any code, it's hard to be certain what is going on at all.